# Where can I get updated list of mcc and mnc (official) of whole world?

Tags: telecom

Is there any website that provides updated list of all MCC (Mobile Country Code) and MNC(Mobile Network Code). Which department is reponsible for allocating these codes ? Is it [ITU](https://www.itu.int) ? I searched their database but couldn't find the updated list. There are few unofficial websites that provide this data but I need the official ones if possible. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

The list at [mcclist.com](http://mcclist.com/mobile-network-codes-country-codes.asp) says it was last updated in June 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You can find such info here: http://www.mcc-mnc.com/.

Link from previous answer (mcclist.com) seems to be dead.